# how can i set the footer position for different templates, if contents is very less footer should be positioned as fixed or else relative position

Tags: html, angular

How can I adjust the footer position, after routing if template contents is less it should be fixed in position, contents in another template is more then footer position should be relative.

### app.component.html

```html
<header>
  Header Contents
</header>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
  <li role="presentation" routerLink="/category" routerLinkActive="activeTab">
  <a><span>Category</span></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" routerLink="/company" routerLinkActive="activeTab">
   <a><span>Company</span></a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>
  Footer Contents
</footer>
```

### company.html

```html
<section> 
  <md-card>
    <div>

    </div>
 </md-card>
</section>
```

### category.html

```html
<section> 
  <md-card>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <th>XYZ</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Nothing</th>
        </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
   </md-card>
 </section>
```

### app.component.ts

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: yes, but in company.html page no contents is present inside div tag. so at that particular template it should be fixed. Then if i navigate to the page category.html page some contents are present (assuming it has lot of contents inside md-card) then footer should be relative

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS class like

```
.fixedClass {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This class can be applied to your footer using `ng-class` attribute

```
<footer ng-class="{fixedClass: expression}">
    Footer Contents
</footer>
```

The expression should determine the 'size' of the content, which is something you should define; if the content is less based on height or number of characters.

Comment: Thank you, but if fixed position is given directly to footer then it is applied to other templates